# Standard way to pass '&' as part of parameter value in querystring

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

For Example: I am calling following action from client.

```
Url: /Controller/Action/name?id=12&code=some&code&&
```

where my parameter values are

```
id = 12
code= 'some&code&&'
```

But at my Controller I am receiving

```
 id = 12
 code= 'some'
```

In a worse case scenario I can work it out by encoding and decoding '&' at both end with certain character.

But hat will be the better solution to do this?

I am looking solution with normal anchor tag not with @Html.ActionLink

Comment: You'll need to urlencode your parameters. As you should be doing anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `encodeURIComponent()` function to URL encode a string. Try this:

```js
var code = encodeURIComponent('some&code&&');
console.log(code);
```

The `code` variable will then hold the string: `some%26code%26%26` which can then be sent in a querystring.